# Why do I get access violation when trying to use a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a class here meant to log where memory is mapped. When I set a specific location on the map to some number, it give me an access violation.

The exact error is Exception thrown at 0x003A5B4B in memorymapperexample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

This is my class. Addpair and clearlocation give errors when called. The map key is a void pointer and the map value is a int. I don't understand why this simple thing is not working.

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class MallocAllocator
{
private:
    map<void *, int> ord;
    int total;
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    MallocAllocator() { }
    template <typename U> MallocAllocator(const MallocAllocator<U>& other) {}
    T* allocate(size_t count)
    {
        return (T*)malloc(count * sizeof(T));
    }
    void deallocate(T* object, size_t n)
    {
        void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(object);
        free(ptr);

    }
    void addpair(void* a, int b)
    {
        ord[a] = b; //ERROR HERE
    }

    void clearlocation(void * a)
    {
        ord[a] = 0; //ERROR HERE TOO
    }
};

MallocAllocator<void*> memoryManager;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout << "Allocating memory..." << endl;
    auto newObject = memoryManager.allocate(size);

    memoryManager.addpair(newObject, size);
    memoryManager.clearlocation(newObject);
    return newObject;
}

void operator delete(void* objectPtr) noexcept
{
    cout << "DEAllocating memory..." << endl;
    void** ptr = reinterpret_cast<void**>(objectPtr);
    memoryManager.deallocate(ptr, 0);
    //free(objectPtr);
}



int main()
{
    int * ima = new int(99);
    delete ima;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I added the whole program

Comment: *I don't understand why this simple thing..* -- This is simple?  Overloading of operator `new`??  Are you running a marathon before learning to walk?

Comment: Does your program output anything other than the "Exception thrown at..." text? E.g. do any of the `cout` statements output? Also, try compiling with debug on - you may get the exact line from which the exception is thrown. If no, try a debugger to find the exact line throwing the exception.

Comment: I meant the map. The new overloading isn't what I was asking about. I was asking why the map is not working properly and maps are generally pretty simple so that's where simple came from.

Comment: Sure, maps are simple:  `#include <map>...std::map<int, int> intMap; intMap[10] = 20;`  That's simple -- what you posted is not.

Comment: It outputs "allocating memory" from the function that called it. When I break the program during the error, it shows me the lines that I have indicated on the main post which is in addpair and if I skip that then another error of the same messeget clearlocation

Comment: If overloading `new` isn't what you're asking about, then remove it. That's the "Minimal" part of a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

Comment: Well I did that originally but the first comment got me to add a complete example.

Comment: @fman So you wrote this code, and you were not ready to debug this yourself?  That's why I stated "running a marathon before learning to walk".

Comment: The first comment asked for an example that was *both minimal and complete*. We're not asking for this just for the sake of being fussy; it is quite possible that overloading `new` is part of the problem, so try removing it, not just in the code you show us, but in the code you're running. If you don't see the sense in this, then just trust us for now.

Comment: @fman -- You have `map<void *, int>` member, and you're globally instantiation `MallocAllocator<void*> memoryManager;`.  That is where everything starts to go downhill.  Why you couldn't point this out as one of your observations?  I took the code, and it bombs out before hitting `main`.  You need to learn to use the debugger, especially for things like this.  Writing code and crossing your fingers hoping it works, well, doesn't work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie did you just happen to load it up around when I did? Quite the coincidence

Answer (score 4):

Found your problem. Running it through VS gave me this stack trace.

```
bleh.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<void * __ptr64,int,std::less<void * __ptr64>,std::allocator<std::pair<void * __ptr64 const,int> >,0> >::_Lbound<void * __ptr64>(void * const & _Keyval) Line 2090 C++
bleh.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<void * __ptr64,int,std::less<void * __ptr64>,std::allocator<std::pair<void * __ptr64 const,int> >,0> >::lower_bound(void * const & _Keyval) Line 1549 C++
bleh.exe!std::map<void * __ptr64,int,std::less<void * __ptr64>,std::allocator<std::pair<void * __ptr64 const,int> > >::_Try_emplace<void * __ptr64 const & __ptr64>(void * const & _Keyval) Line 210    C++
bleh.exe!std::map<void * __ptr64,int,std::less<void * __ptr64>,std::allocator<std::pair<void * __ptr64 const,int> > >::try_emplace<>(void * const & _Keyval) Line 230   C++
bleh.exe!std::map<void * __ptr64,int,std::less<void * __ptr64>,std::allocator<std::pair<void * __ptr64 const,int> > >::operator[](void * const & _Keyval) Line 339  C++
bleh.exe!MallocAllocator<void * __ptr64>::addpair(void * a, int b) Line 80  C++
bleh.exe!operator new(unsigned __int64 size) Line 97    C++
[External Code] 
bleh.exe!MallocAllocator<void * __ptr64>::MallocAllocator<void * __ptr64>() Line 66 C++
bleh.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'memoryManager''() Line 89    C++
[External Code]
```

The stack reveals that the program is in the initialization of `memoryManager` when something calls `new` (I guess `std::map` is trying to allocate something). But of course, you've overloaded `new` to use `memoryManager` which has not been fully initialized yet! Bummer. And it throws the error when trying to get the root node of the `std::map` which doesn't give a sensible value.

Debugging is an enormously useful skill.

**Edit:** compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 bleh.cpp` and running through `gdb` gives me a different but equally troubling result.

```
#0  0x00007ffff756a648 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff78b0400 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0x402597, n=20) at fileops.c:1320
#1  0x00007ffff755fe6d in __GI__IO_fwrite (buf=<optimized out>, size=1, count=20, fp=0x7ffff78b0400 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at iofwrite.c:43
#2  0x00007ffff7b7f63e in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) ()  from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7b7f947 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0000000000400d11 in operator new(unsigned long) ()
#5  0x000000000040228b in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) ()
#6  0x0000000000402142 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> > > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> > >&, unsigned long) ()
#7  0x0000000000401d75 in std::_Rb_tree<void*, std::pair<void* const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::_M_get_node() ()
#8  0x00000000004015cd in std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> >* std::_Rb_tree<void*, std::pair<void* const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::_M_create_node<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) ()
#9  0x0000000000401368 in std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<void* const, int> > std::_Rb_tree<void*, std::pair<void* const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::_M_emplace_hint_unique<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) ()
#10 0x0000000000401122 in std::map<void*, int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::operator[](void* const&) ()
#11 0x0000000000400ee4 in MallocAllocator<void*>::addpair(void*, int) ()
#12 0x0000000000400d4a in operator new(unsigned long) ()
#13 0x000000000040228b in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) ()
#14 0x0000000000402142 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> > > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> > >&, unsigned long) ()
#15 0x0000000000401d75 in std::_Rb_tree<void*, std::pair<void* const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::_M_get_node() ()
#16 0x00000000004015cd in std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<void* const, int> >* std::_Rb_tree<void*, std::pair<void* const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::_M_create_node<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) ()
#17 0x0000000000401368 in std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<void* const, int> > std::_Rb_tree<void*, std::pair<void* const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, int> > >::_M_emplace_hint_unique<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<void* const, int> >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<void* const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) ()
#   ... ad inifintum ...
```

This time, the program is setting up one of its streams `std::cout` by the looks of it. And tries to allocate memory. Looks like `memoryManager` happened to be set up right or actually initialized properly. Either way when it tries to allocate something your allocator causes a new node to be created in `std::map`. Which requires memory allocation. Which requires creating a new node... See where I'm going with this? The stack trace repeats like this for quite a while.

All in all, `std::map` is a bad internal structure to use for this. (Actually most of the standard containers would cause similar problems).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. This makes sense. Isn't memorymanager initialized though so it should work

Comment: @fman -- `memorymanager` is *not* initialized.  It is during the initialization that your member variable `map<void *, int>` needs to  be initialized since it is a member variable.  You would see that your program is calling the default constructor of `memorymanager` before `main` has been executed.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for getting that info. so it is an infinite recursion